accessing dict values in JSON with Python
I have the following JSON data (1st set below) followed by coding to load the json (2nd set below). I'm not figuring out how to iterate and append rows for each 'stationID' to extract 'CircuitName', 'DewPoint', and 'WindSpeed' under 'values':
ACTUAL JSON
[
    {
        "stationId": "X",
        "date": "2024-08-14T08:00:00-07:00",
        "values": {
            "CircuitName": "Test",
            "DewPoint": 39.39,
            "WindSpeed": 5/5
        }
    },
    {
        "stationId": "Y",
        "date": "2024-08-14T08:00:00-07:00",
        "values": {
            "CircuitName": "Test2",
            "DewPoint": 55,
            "WindSpeed": 0.888
        }
    }

]

CODE:
    req = requests.get(api_request_url, params=params, headers=headers)
    data = json.loads(req.text)

    rows = []
    for i in data:
            row = {
                "stationId": i["stationId"],
                "CircuitName": i["values"],
            }

            rows.append(row)


you can do "CircuitName": i["values"]["CircuitName"]

FYI you can simplify json.loads(req.text) to req.json().

Use a list comprehension to extract it directly(more efficient).
For example:
rows = [
    {
        "stationId": i["stationId"],
        "CircuitName": i["values"]["CircuitName"],
        "DewPoint": i["values"]["DewPoint"],
        "WindSpeed": i["values"]["WindSpeed"]
    }
    for i in data
]

print(rows)

